# How to pull single split characters together using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

For a tokenizer my goal is to split a term up such that I obtain only the words (length > 1). Now to cover also single characters I want to pull all single characters that follow after each other together, like so:

```
Q S. C Headquarter -> qsc headquarter
```

I match like this using python:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?u)\b\w+\b")
pattern.findall("Q S. C Headquarter")
```

Of course I compile the regex because I have to fit it multiple times. The above pattern will return ['Q', 'S', 'C', 'Headquarter'] while I expect ['QSC', 'Headquarter'].

Comment: Doing in 2 steps would be easier

Comment: Yes in 2 steps it is indeed easy. But I wonder if there is a nice regex way of doing it one-line

Comment: Would `['Q S. C', 'Headquarter']` be OK?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't got an answer to my comment/question, but assuming it's OK to include the spaces in the "joined character words" you could try this regex:

```
((?:(?<=\s|^)\w\.?\s(?!\w\w)|(?<=\s|^)\w\.?(?=\s))+|\S+)
```

**It tests for**

- a letter, preceded by a space or start of line (positive look-behind)
- optionally followed by a `.`
- then followed by space
  -- **not** followed by two or more letters (negative look-ahead)

**or**

- a letter, preceded by a space or start of line (positive look-behind)
- optionally followed by a `.`
- followed by a space  (positive look-ahead)

This is repeated until no match.

**If none of the above**

- a sequence of non-space characters

(Note! The term letter above is really the regex *word character class* - i.e. an ASCII letter, a digit or an underscore `_`.)

The first test fins initial or intermediate *single characters* to form a word. The second, the final character before a *normal* word, to avoid capturing the final space. And the third test are for words of 2 or more characters. I choose to test for *non space* here instead of *word character* to be able to grab acronyms, abbreviations and such. E.g. `Q&A` or `e.g.`. It also captures and alike.

[See an example at regex101 here.](https://regex101.com/r/qK5oX7/2)

Hope this helps.

Finally, if the spaces absolutely can't be included, *I* see no other way then doing it in two steps.

Regards